# Error while Running python shell in node js

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to run this piece of code from my node js application

```
from pytube import YouTube
import sys

vid_link=sys.argv[1]
yt =YouTube(str(vid_link))
video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
video.download()
```

here's the index.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var  {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let videolink=req.body.vlink;

    var options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python', 
      pythonOptions: ['-u'],
      scriptPath: '/home/haldhar/Desktop/ytapp',
      args: ['videolink']
    };

    PythonShell.run('script.py', options, function (err, results) {
      if (err) throw err;
      // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
      console.log('results: %j', results);
    });
})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`))
```

The error i'm getting is (pytube is already installed):

```
 Error: ImportError: No module named pytube
        at PythonShell.parseError (/home/haldhar/Desktop/ytapp/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:295:21)
        at terminateIfNeeded (/home/haldhar/Desktop/ytapp/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:190:32)
        at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/haldhar/Desktop/ytapp/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:182:13)
        at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
        ----- Python Traceback -----
        File "/home/haldhar/Desktop/ytapp/script1.py", line 2, in <module>
          from pytube import YouTube
```

please help me with how to run a script in a node js application

Comment: Are you able to run the python script manually? Are you using a virtual environment (venv) for the python script?

Comment: yes i'm able to run the scipt manually and no i'm not using virtual environment to run it

Comment: Maybe you need in the `options`, `pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python3'`?